# Issue In Aligning Images With Bootstrap4

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align images with Bootstrap 4. I've used `.row` within a `.container`. I now have whitespace between images and I don't want it to be that way. I want the images aligned immediately next to each other without any spaces. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<div class="container mycontainer">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="one">   <!-- FIRST ROW LEFT SIDE-->
            <img src="./images-for-sample/images-for-sample/investors-img-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="two">    <!-- FIRST ROW RIGHT SIDE-->
            <img src="./images-for-sample/images-for-sample/investors-img-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-4">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="three">   <!-- SECOND ROW LEFT SIDE-->
             <img src="./images-for-sample/images-for-sample/investors-img-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="four">    <!-- SECOND ROW RIGHT SIDE-->
             <img src="./images-for-sample/images-for-sample/investors-img-5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-5">
         </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="five">   <!-- THIRD ROW LEFT SIDE-->
            <img src="./images-for-sample/images-for-sample/investors-img-3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="six">    <!-- THIRD ROW RIGHT SIDE-->
            <img src="./images-for-sample/images-for-sample/investors-img-6.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-6">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The output I get currently is:

[image: Output-Image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your targeted goal you have to remove Bootstrap's paddings for each div and set the images width to 100% of those:

```
// you could also use img as a selector
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}

// this is the selector of your div's
.col-sm-12 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

However, due to your current implementation this would result in the following ([for a running fiddle click here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4c7z9qa/2/)):

[image: First solution with whitespaces]

If you additionally want to remove the whitespaces shown in the image, you could use [Bootstrap's card columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-columns) like this:

```
<div class="card-columns">

    <div class="card" id="one">    <!-- FIRST ROW LEFT SIDE-->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-1">
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="two">    <!-- FIRST ROW RIGHT SIDE-->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-4">
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="three">   <!-- SECOND ROW LEFT SIDE-->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-2">
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="four">    <!-- SECOND ROW RIGHT SIDE-->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-5">
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="five">   <!-- THIRD ROW LEFT SIDE-->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-3">
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="six">    <!-- THIRD ROW RIGHT SIDE-->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="photo-6">
    </div>

</div>
```

and adjust it with some css to your need:

```
// the default column count is 1 and there should not be a space between the columns
.card-columns {
  column-count: 1;
  column-gap: 0;
}

// for medium devices and larger set the count to two
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

// reset card's margin bottom
.card {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

// scale images properly to fit the divs
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Second solution without whitespaces]

You can find the running fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4c7z9qa/42/).

If you are using Bootstrap 3, have a look at [this Medium article](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643).

Good luck!